# Where does Total Commander store file comments?

Tags: file-management, storage, total-commander, comments

The feature is in Files > Edit comment

[image: Total commander file comment]

I thought that it's stored in [NTFS ADS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Alternate_data_streams_(ADS)) but `dir /R` doesn't show any additional streams. I've also checked \AppData\Roaming\GHISLER and \AppData\Local\GHISLER but found nothing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comments are stored in the `descript.ion` file within the same directory.

Both this format as well as TotalCmd itself predate NTFS ADS – usage of descript.ion was inherited from MS-DOS file management software such as Norton Commander. (Hence the "Use DOS font" checkbox.)